# Vim E854: path too long for completion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, autocomplete

I have a Rails RSpec file which looks something like

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Something" do
  ...
end
```

When I try to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to autocomplete anything in that file, I get:

[image: Screenshot of the error message]

Text version:

```
Scanning included file: spec_helper.rb
E854: path too long for completion
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

If I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> this, it completes my word perfectly.

To avoid Vim to autocomplete by using included files I can do:

```
:set complete-=i
```

But that's not the root of the issue.

How can I fix this?

Comment: See [this other question about the exact same elusive error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9401762/546861).

Comment: That doesn't fix the problem. Actually @npiv recompiled the project to extirpate the error from the source code... won't be doing that.

Comment: The problem is a bug in Vim or one of its support files. Either you wait until someone fixes it upstream or you go ahead and do what npiv did.

Comment: Why do you say it's a bug in Vim ? is it reported ? if it is you could respond that as an answer :)

Comment: I've put the link in a comment because everything has already been said and done in the other thread. If you read it carefully you'll see that the "naive" option is to remove the parts of the code that display the error and that someone is hinting at a much more precise problem/solution that even come with a patch **and** a (supposedly) working `ruby.vim`.

Comment: Where is ruby.vim located ? I tried find . -name ruby.vim under ~/.vim without success ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok,

It results that I am using MacVim, and like *romainl* commented in the original post, the issue is related to a bug in ruby.vim. In this Stack Overflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401762/what-function-does-vim-call-for-completion-with-ctrl-n) the third answer candidate actually suggests a possible cause (correctly), which is related to a bug in ruby.vim ( an old version is using a deprecated function ).

MacVim (Snapshot 64) is supplied with the old rails.vim, so to fix this I went into `MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/ftplugin` and did wget to the raw file in the official rails.vim plug-in [repo](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/tree/master/ftplugin)

This fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Not sure if the plugin has changed name, but the raw file that fixed it for me was: https://raw.github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/master/ftplugin/ruby.vim

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the issue for me also and I'm on plain old vim, not MacVim. You just need to replace ruby.vim in the vim runtime directory, to find the runtime in vim do `:echo $VIMRUNTIME`, then the file will be in that dir under ftplugin/ruby.vim, and I happened to grab the newer file using `wget https://raw.github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/master/ftplugin/ruby.vim` Thanks for your help guys this was an annoying side-effect of compiling my own vim due to a separate bug and wanting to use the Command-T plugin.